# How to remove an object from an array using lodash?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, lodash

I have a variable that looks something like this

```
[ { url : "http:image.gif"}, { url : "http:image.gif"} , { url : "http:image.gif"}]
```

I would like a function that goes through and removes one object each time the function is called until there are no more items left.

something like

```
function Decrement(){

    if array is not empty

        var lastKey = _.last (object);  

        var updatedObject = _.without ( object, lastkey); 

        return the last key of the new updatedObject

}
```

Comment: `array.pop(); return array[array.length-1];` if you're trying to return the last item in the array *after* removing one, or just `return array.pop()` if you want to return the one being removed. You don't need an if statement if you're happy to return `undefined` once the array is empty. You don't need Lodash for such a simple operation. (`array.shift()` to remove the first element.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a combination of JavaScript's [**pop**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) and lodash's [**_.last**](https://lodash.com/docs#last):

```
function decrement(array) {
  array.pop();
  return _.last(array);
}
```

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3];

function decrement(array) {
  array.pop();
  return _.last(array);
}

var result = decrement(a);
console.log(result, a);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```